# dafny assertion violation error, not sure what the reason is

Tags: dafny

I am very new to Dafny. It is complaining here that there is an assertion error:

```
method Fred () returns (result : int) {
  var number : int;
  result := number * number;
  
  assert result > 0;

}
```

I am trying to write an assertion that expresses the following statement: the square of any integer is non-negative

Answer (score 1):

The assertion passes if you change it to `result >= 0`. Is that what you meant? If `number` is 0, then `result` will be 0 too.